# Have height of embedded Vimeo link scale proportionately to width

Tags: html, video, responsive-design, embed, vimeo

I used the embed code Vimeo spits out to place a video on a page. I was able to get the width to scale within my responsive setup, but the height stays constant (leaving black bars once you get down to smaller viewports.

Link to page: http://imwillryan.com/iceland.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few different things after doing some more searching, but this Responsify plugin was a simple CSS-only fix.

https://github.com/mikerodham/responsify